# открыть окно системных настроек

Tags: android, activity, settings, android-intent

Подскажите пожалуйста как из программы открыть окно настроек "*Точка доступа WLAN*".

```
startActivity(
new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

Данный код открывает окно настроек "Беспроводные сети", но до окна "*Точка доступа WLAN* " еще два перехода сделать нужно.

Ближе не могу подобраться, может кто знает, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

и еще, может потребовать права

```
android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS
```

---

**UPDATE**

Для управления (включение/отключение) WiFi hostspot нужно,

права

```
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

и сам код

```
 /**
 * включение/отключение WiFi hostspot.
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param isTurnToOn
 */
public static void turnOnOffHotspot(Context context, boolean isTurnToOn) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiApControl apControl = WifiApControl.getApControl(wifiManager);
    if (apControl != null) {

    // ЕСЛИ WIFI ВКЛЮЧЕН, ОТКЛЮЧИТЕ ЕЕ СПЕРВА
    //if (isWifiOn(context) && isTurnToOn) {
    //  turnOnOffWifi(context, false);
    //}

    // Тут включается Hotspot
    apControl.setWifiApEnabled(apControl.getWifiApConfiguration(), isTurnToOn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Android 5.1, появляется окно "Точка доступа (APN)", очень быстро исчезает, но всетаки я увидел, что в нем ничего нет, только название окна. Хотелось бы окно - "Точка доступа WLAN" или на англ. "WLAN hotspot".

Comment: если нужен hotspot тогда думаю поможет `ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS`

Comment: Я пробовал, все что есть близко напоминающее WiFi или WLAN из списка:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html не подходит, может дополнительные параметры в интент закинуть, но какие, и как и что? ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS - это просто окно включения WiFi для приема, а нужно раздача WiFi.

Comment: ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS - это окно включения WiFi для приема, а нужно раздача WiFi. Saidolim все равно спасибо. Может думаю просто включать "точку доступа" и сразу закрывать приложение finish(); И вместо пяти кликов, по одному клику буду включать интернет. А знаете как включать из программы "точку доступа"?

Comment: WifiApControl - такого нет класса и не импортируется, нашел в https://github.com/mvdan/accesspoint/blob/master/library/src/main/java/cc/mvdan/accesspoint/WifiApControl.java                       и вот там такую сложную конструкцию навернули  - method.invoke() и всякое такое, мне нужно одну строчку выдернуть из кода бибилиотеки -ВКЛ AP WiFi.

Comment: А у Вас Saidolim смотрю Studio не ругается -  WifiApControl - синенький, совсем не красный:) Как вы так добились?